# How does a capacitor coupled voltage transformer (CCVT) and spark gap work?

Tags: voltage, power, capacitor, transformer, spark

What is the actual purpose of a capacitor coupled voltage transformer in a substation?

What I do know is that they offer low impedance to the very high frequency signal, so it does not get into the substation and damage any equipment. What happens to this signal after it takes the path of the CCVT? Does it just dissipate?

Secondly, the system voltage is stepped down to a more usable voltage of 115/69V through the means of capacitor stacks and windings. What is this secondary voltage used for? Does this secondary voltage power equipment or is the voltage used as a signal for metering/relaying?

Lastly, I know CCVTs have a spark gap device that fires when a transient occurs usually due to a fault. Why does the spark gap fire during an overvoltage? What is the purpose of it firing? I know that a spark gap misfiring or not firing when it should creates carrier holes in the communication system, but I don't know how or why the spark gap is firing to begin with, and what information is being relayed to what when it does fire.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but this website (https://megger.com/electrical-tester/may-2023/coupling-capacitor-voltage-transformers-(ccvts)) suggests that CCVTs are for instrumentation, not noise reduction or damage protection. Do you have a link to somewhere that talks about noise reduction/damage stuff?

Comment: There are a few topics mentioned here that don't seem to go together, and it would help if you can explain their relevance, or just remove them if unrelated: Where did you see/hear about CCVTs, what is your context, where are you coming from here? What high-frequency signals? What spark gap? What are "carrier holes", in what "communication system"? A spark gap might be used for overvoltage protection, *and that's it*, so it's unclear what you're asking at the end here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't work directly in MV/HV applications but was responsible for organising maintenance of half a dozen 10 kV, 1 MVA - 2 MVA transformers on an industrial site.

> What is the actual purpose of a capacitor coupled voltage transformer in a substation.

They offer a means of measuring voltage or phase indication without the power dissipation of a resistor and without the high-voltage problems with connecting a signal transformer to the MV/HV supply. (Think of how you would insulate the primary windings on a 5 VA instrumentation transformer!)

> What I do know is they offer low impedance to the very high frequency signal, so it does not get into the substation and damage any equipment. What happens to this signal after it takes the path of the CCVT? Does it just dissipate?

I'm not sure what this knowledge is related to. Certainly a capacitor across the lines will offer a low impedance to noise / HF on the line but they'd need to be huge to handle transients. I was shown capacitor couplers used to inject and receive data communication over the HV transmission network. Capacitors are generally designed to have low internal resistance so power dissipation is not (usually) a problem.

> Secondly, the system voltage is stepped down to a more usable voltage of 115/69V through the means of capacitor stacks and windings. What I don't know is, what is this secondary voltage used for?
> Does this secondary voltage power equipment, or is the voltage used as a signal for metering/relaying?

It's used for metering and monitoring (over / under-voltage, earth faults, etc.).

> Lastly, I know CCVT's have a spark gap device that fires when a transient occurs usually due to a fault. My questions are, why does the spark gap fire during an overvoltage, and what is the purpose of it firing?

The gap is set at a distance calculated to break down at a certain voltage. This will be set at a voltage higher than the normal operating voltage but lower than the maximum withstand voltage of any devices that it is protecting. This includes transformers, switchgear, overhead line insulation, underground cable installation, customer supply, etc.

> I know that a spark gap misfiring or not firing when it should creates carrier holes in the communication system,

"Carrier holes"? Interruptions, maybe, but I'd expect it to interruptions to be worse when the spark gap is breaking down as the corona will introduce a lot of noise.

> ... but I don't know how or why the spark gap is firing to begin with,

Overvoltage due to lightning or network faults.

> ... and what information is being relayed to what when it does fire?

The spark gaps do not relay information. They protect the line and the equipment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very helpful! I work for a utility and it's surprising the amount of knowledge people don't have on this equipment. The reference to the high frequency signal was in regard to the communication between substations with line tuners and wave traps.